# Disabled internal display and accidentily disabled all monitors

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, display-driver, laptop-display, asus

I have a semi old (3 year) ASUS ROG (gaming laptop). Last year I broke it's screen pretty badly and a replacement has not been made because I thought I'm just going to build a PC. Long story short, I was using the laptop as a PC with external monitors connected to it. the laptop was getting pretty heated up, probably because it was trying to display to the 2 external monitors and its internal one (even thought it is shattered beyond comprehension and is now good only for visualizing beautiful rainbow cracks).

So I decided to be a smart guy and decided to disable the internal display from the monitors from the Device Manager. All 3 monitors went black and so did my mood for the evening. I have no way of re-enabling anything and I'm desperate.

Things that I tried:

- Logging in (blindly (not sure If I logged in)) and checking If I can change screens with Windows + P
- Logging in (blindly (not sure If I logged in)) and spamming FN + F9 (ASUS ROG Monitor Switch key)
- Entering Safe Modes, BIOS-es etc ... (no way of knowing if I succeeded)
- I do not know If I succeeded with any of these actions, due to my main laptop monitor presenting me with only rainbow-colored cracks and my external monitors being completely black.

If anyone knows any idea like:

- Key combination for enabling or switching hardware monitor
- Key combination for re-enabling internal display
- A way to remotely connect to the laptop (somehow... anyhow) without much action from the laptop because I am literally completely blind in terms of actions on it.

I would be very thankful for any proposals on how I should proceed with this problem.

Comment: If you find another computer, you could RDP to the laptop and undo the changes. If you don't have another computer, you may find an RDP app for your phone, when connected to the same local network/router.

Comment: @harrymc Forgot to mention I tried that, but didn't have RDP enabled on my laptop. Anyway the issue is fixed exactly with RDP after enabling it, so this is a good proposal. Thanks! ... Semi-solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The proposal of @harrymc in one of the comments is an excellent solution if you have Remote Desktop enabled. I didn't. Long story - short, after posting in 10-ish forums about it and seeing that the answers on those solutions relied solely on the fact that any of the monitors will be working, (which is not the case with me) I decided to post the fix that I found after really much trial and error.

NOTE: This is not some hardware genius or something very clever, but If you are in the desperate situation I was in, it is probably your only hope, aside from just straight up buying a new laptop display and replacing your old broken one...

I had another laptop next to me, so I just decided to follow up on an idea. I knew I had Telegram on my laptop, so:

- I just restarted the laptop
- logged in (assumed that I logged in, didn't really know).
- Opened Telegram through Start Menu (Windows button + typing in Telegram and just enter) ... Only keyboard usage when doing it completely blind
- Worked my way to the first chat with Tab and Arrow keys
- Print Screen and send to chat

It worked, I had to spam a friend with some screenshots till I fix it, but It's something I'm willing to do.

The next part was just mimicking the exact amount of Tabs, Arrow Key presses and etc. from the other laptop, in order to enable Remote Desktop and check the Device Name. After that I just connected with RDP and what I found out through the Device Management is just preposterous.

By displaying the Internal Monitor (I am sure I disabled only the Internal Monitor) Somehow both my external NVIDIA and all other Monitor devices were disabled simultaneously. I cannot fathom what is the logic behind this...

So, I'm leaving the question and my last-resort fix (last-resort, because you should use it only if all other fixes fail). If anyone has any other ideas on how similar problems can be fixed, post answer below.

Short note: If you don't have Telegram or some chatting tool available you should still be able to open a browser or something and from there upload screenshots, but you'd have to do a lot of precise key presses in blind mode - which is possible with mimicking from another laptop, but it's still annoying.

Hope this helps someone else ... Moral of story: Never touch the Internal Display Monitor...

Answer (score 0):

I did sorta the same thing but with Facebook, took a bit due to not having the actual app, but I thankfully was logged into my Facebook and I decided to call my alt and once I received the call on my phone I was the happiest person in the world, I was able to navigate to device manager through the vc and reenable the monitor

Btw you can either do second screen only display or just close your laptop if you don't want it running two screens

Its what I did to help with the lag (my laptop was already a bit laggy because I didn't change any settings, changed alot n its good now)

sadly can't go into bios mode with broken screen though due to monitors not working enless I fully disable my screen though.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1174578)